# Mongodb: replace index by same index with collation

Tags: mongodb

there is a big colllection `test1` with index on `field`. It has no collation.

```
db.test1.createIndex({field: 1});
```

I need to replace this index by same index with collation:

```
db.test1.createIndex({field: 1}, {collation: {locale: "en_US", strength: 2}})
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "An index with the same key pattern, but a different collation already exists with the same name.  Try again with a unique name. Existing index: { v: 2, key: { field: 1.0 }, name: \"field_1\", ns: \"test.test1\" } Requested index: { v: 2, key: { field: 1.0 }, name: \"field_1\", ns: \"test.test1\", collation: { locale: \"en_US\", caseLevel: false, caseFirst: \"off\", strength: 2, numericOrdering: false, alternate: \"non-ignorable\", maxVariable: \"punct\", normalization: false, backwards: false, version: \"57.1\" } }", 
    "code" : 85.0, 
    "codeName" : "IndexOptionsConflict"
}
```

It need to remove old index and add new. The problem is that the application always needs an index

Comment: Rolling upgrade? Are you using a Replica Set? If not then you probably need one and should start adding nodes. If you're sitting there waiting for a programming solution, then there is not one. You either live without the index or you have the means to do a rolling update of indexes on secondaries whilst off-line and then demote the primary and roll out the new index there as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn This is a replica. Rolling upgrade is more difficult but possible way. I would like to resort to it if there are no other ways.

Comment: There really is not another option. If you can set up cloud manager then it's pretty simple to automate even. But of course you going to need to bring each node down to even do that even. There's no magic pill here and the process is pretty painless if a bit repetitive depending on how many nodes you need to update things on.